# How to Run script through Graphical interface instead of console

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

First , I want to apologize because I a beginner and don’t know the keyword to search for my problem.

Background of the problem:

I'm currently writing the program for robot by using python api. Since this is a desktop robot, all the code will run through my computer. I currently have two function scripts, one for automate the robot and one for calibrate the home function for robot. I had designed a GUI for user to choose option. So my GUI had 2 option , option 1 is home calibrate and option 2 is automate.

What I want :

How could I connect the script of robot function to option on the GUI? For example, when user choose option 1 on GUI (home calibrate), the script home function will automate run without running through console (don’t have to type `python3 home_calibrate.py` on console )

Note: my GUI use tkinter and my robot will control by python api (design by company of the robot)

Comment: Post your GUI code, so people can review it. Typically, the user selects an option and clicks a button that triggers a function (callback).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple GUI made with tkinter that has two buttons. When you click `button1`, `function1()` is called and when you click `button2`, `function2()` is called

So you can just replace the two functions with your functions

```
import tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Define the two custom functions
def function1():
    print("Button 1 clicked")

def function2():
    print("Button 2 clicked")

# Create the two buttons
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button 1", command=function1)
button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Button 2", command=function2)

# Pack the buttons
button1.pack()
button2.pack()

# Run the main loop
root.mainloop()
```